# Error compilation kernel

Tags: compiler-errors, compilation, linux-kernel, kernel

Trying to compile a linux kernel on Ubuntu 16.04 for an embedded board and I have this error during make :

```
fatal error: mach/cputype.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

The board I use is the TMDSLCDK138 integrating the OMAPL138. I installed the TI SDK from here http://software-dl.ti.com/sdoemb/sdoemb_public_sw/mcsdk/latest1/index_FDS.html and in the installation folder there is a custom linux SDK called "linux-3.3-psp03.22.00.06.sdk". This is what I did so far :
`sudo make O=/home/BOB/omapbuild/omap_linux/ menuconfig`
To configure the kernel for my board.
And next :
 `sudo make O=/home/BOB/omapbuild/omap_linux/`
And it is here where I got the error.
All my headers are up to date.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/75709/how-do-i-install-kernel-header-files  might help!!

Comment: Thank you, I tried the solution but it is already the newest version (4.4.0-31.50).

Comment: Sounds like you're cross compiling and didn't set `ARCH` properly.   (i.e. `make ARCH=arm64`)

Comment: Instead of asking for guesses, you need to do a better job of describing what you are doing.

Comment: Which command did you use to compile ? which board ? which target ?

Comment: Another thing, you could try running `make V=1 -O=whereever`, and check the `-I` flags of the command that caused the error, to see which directories are being included to see why the file cannot be found.

Comment: (1) You should not have to be superuser to cross-compile a kernel. I.E. drop the `sudo`. (2) What toolchain are you using?  Is it in your **PATH** (e.g. `echo $PATH`)?  Are there **ARCH** and **CROSS_COMPILE** variables defined in your shell environment (e.g. `printenv`)? (3) Did you go through all the menus of `make menuconfig` for your board?  Usually there's a **<board>_defconfig** file to configure the board's defaults.

Comment: (1) I have to put sudo otherwise I have a permission issue. (2) I think the toolchain is automatically used (it is in the folder) so I don't have to add it in the PATH. ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE are not defined. (3) I have imported the defaults config file for my board using menuconfig.

Comment: (1) Your use of `sudo` indicates your build environment is setup incorrectly. (2a) There is no such thing as *"automatic use"* of a toolchain, so your *"thinking"* is flawed,  (2b) There is no toolchain included with the kernel source (nor stored in its source directories). (2c) You apparently don't understand how PATH works, so you could not be invoking the proper toolchain for cross-compiling.  (2d) The omission of ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE variables in either your environment or **make** command means that you're trying to  perform a native compile (e.g. x86), rather than a cross compile.

Comment: @sawdust Thank you for your help, I found the solution ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments I could compile the kernel by setting up the good environment:

```
export ARCH=arm
export PATH=/home/bob/ti/mcsdk_1_01_00_02/linux-devkit/sysroots/i686-arago-linux/usr/bin/:$PATH
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-arago-linux-gnueabi-
```

and then for the TMDSLCDK138 board :

```
make tisdk_omapl138-lcdk_defconfig
make uImage
```