# How can i make the busybox1.23.2 Compile success？

Tags: linux, arm, busybox

package: busybox
    version: 1.23.2
    when i make busybox , it produces unexpected results.
    the crosschaintool i use is  ARM/uClinux Toolchain arm-2010q1-189-arm-   uclinuxeabi-i686-pc-linux-gnu，but i can't make the busybox,like this:

```
root@ubuntu:/busybox/busybox-1.23.2# make
  SPLIT   include/autoconf.h -> include/config/*
  GEN     include/bbconfigopts.h
  HOSTCC  applets/usage
applets/usage.c: In function ‘main’:
applets/usage.c:52:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(STDOUT_FILENO, usage_array[i].usage, strlen(usage_array[i].usage) + 1);
   ^
  GEN     include/usage_compressed.h
  HOSTCC  applets/applet_tables
applets/applet_tables.c: In function ‘main’:
applets/applet_tables.c:161:4: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    fgets(line_old, sizeof(line_old), fp);
    ^
  GEN     include/applet_tables.h
  CC      applets/applets.o
  LD      applets/built-in.o
  HOSTCC  applets/usage_pod
applets/usage_pod.c: In function ‘main’:
applets/usage_pod.c:74:3: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   printf(usage_array[i].aname);
   ^
  CC      libbb/appletlib.o
  CC      libbb/vfork_daemon_rexec.o
  AR      libbb/lib.a
  CC      shell/hush.o
shell/hush.c: In function 'builtin_source':
shell/hush.c:8901: warning: 'sv.sv_g_malloced' may be used uninitialized in this function
shell/hush.c:8901: warning: 'sv.sv_g_argc' may be used uninitialized in this function
shell/hush.c:8901: warning: 'sv.sv_g_argv' may be used uninitialized in this function
shell/hush.c:8901: warning: 'sv.sv_argv0' may be used uninitialized in this function
  AR      shell/lib.a
  LINK    busybox_unstripped
Trying libraries: crypt m
 Library crypt is not needed, excluding it
 Library m is not needed, excluding it
Final link with: <none>
arm-uclinuxeabi-strip:busybox_unstripped: File format not recognized
Makefile:723: recipe for target 'busybox' failed
make: *** [busybox] Error 1
```

how should i do?      is the busybox can't use the ARM/uClinux Toolchain? how should i do ？we'll really appreciate it if you can give us some advice and some pieces of guidance，thanks！

Comment: Does this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42696662/error-compilation-kernel/42786729#42786729) apply to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> LINK    busybox_unstripped Trying libraries: crypt m  Library crypt
>   is not needed, excluding it  Library m is not needed, excluding it
>   Final link with:  arm-uclinuxeabi-strip:busybox_unstripped: File
>   format not recognized Makefile:723: recipe for target 'busybox' failed
>   make: *** [busybox] Error 1

As there is only a piece of the whole compiling log, some suggestions are:

1) Please check the compiling log from the beginning whether there are other important warnings or errors.

2) busybox_unstripped file is generated or not?  Check the makefile dependencies to find out whether all dependencies files are successfully generated. From the log, some libraries are excluded so that you may have to check the busybox configuration file.

3) If busybox_unstripped file is generated, check the makefile about the link grammar of "Final link with:". For the cross-tool chain to link successfully, please make sure the link command is correct.

Good luck!